# You shouldn't be jealous of the likes of her

Tags: sentence-construction

> You shouldn't be jealous of the likes of her.

Is this a correct construct? Sounds unusual to me but I am unable to find any error. Google search returned some similar sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"the likes of her, them, him, you". is an idiom. It means: people like her, him, them, you.

It is an idiom.

The likes of [some person]=people like [some person].

It can also be used for things (less usual).

["the likes of" in the Collins Dictionary online](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/the-likes-of)

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/likes-of-someone-something) has a good example sentence of the "used for things" you mention: _They’re competing with the likes of IBM and Unisys._

Comment: @Lambie Congratulations on getting past 20K. And +1 for this answer.